# ALTER TABLE yii2 MIGRATION

Tags: mysql, yii2, migration, mysql-8.0

When I updated MYSQL 8.0.29 +, I got new default algorithm.

"INSTANT is the default algorithm as of MySQL 8.0.29, and INPLACE before that."

But XtraBackup dont want to make a backup with this ALGO:

here is about this:

https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/em/instant.html

When I  use "addColumn" to my migration. This is running AlterTable and change my ALGO to INSTANT, and I cant use XtraBackup.

So question:

How Can I run migration like this in yii2?:

"mysql> alter table sbtest1 add column h int(11) default null,algorithm=inplace;"

in this construction:

$this->addColumn('sbtest', 'h', $this->integer(11));

or maybe you know the better solution.

Thanks

$this->addColumn('sbtest', 'h', $this->integer(11));

Answer (score 0):

The `yii\db\ColumnSchemaBuilder` has method `append()` that allows you to put any SQL fragment you want to append to column type.
So, you can try adding it like this:

```php
$this->addColumn('sbtest', 'h', $this->integer(11)->append(', ALGORITHM=INPLACE'));
```

But there is one issue. Position statements (`FIRST`, `AFTER ...`) and `CHECK` statement are added after the `append()` part. So `append()` will only work if you don't use `first()`, `after()` or `check()` methods.

Another option is to give up `ColumnSchemaBuilder` and simply write the type as string:

```php
$this->addColumn('sbtest', 'h', 'INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, ALGORITHM=INPLACE');
```